# Unable to retrieve names of all folders in s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using `list_objects_v2` to get list of folders in s3 bucket

The below function is being used to get folder names

```
def get_folders(source_bucket):
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=source_bucket)
    for page in pages:
        for obj in page['Contents']:
            if obj['Key'].endswith('/'):
                folders.append(obj['Key'])
    return folders
```

Not all folders are returned. The function is returning only the following few folders:

```
check_multiple_extract/
dataset_cities/ 
epex_dayahead_auction_half_hourly/ 
multiple_schedule_schedule_1/
penguins_sql_server/
penguins_sql_server_bcp/
penguins_sql_server_bcp_append/
run_sql_commands/
test/
```

The bucket contains the following folders (20 folders)

[image]

Can someone please assist on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's import to realize that there are no directories in S3.

S3 does have a concept of a common prefix, but that is a convenience factor only, allowing you to list objects that have a shared common prefix.  Some presentation layers for S3 treat this as a concept similar to directories, but they are distinct concepts.  Unlike directories, a common prefix is just that, a prefix that some objects share, it does not exist outside of the fact that some objects share a prefix.

Notably: The AWS Web Interface allows you to create empty "folders".  In actuality it is creating a zero-byte object with a trailing slash to create the common prefix purely for UI purposes.  Again, directories don't exist in S3, just objects, so it must make an object to create the common prefix for you.
These are the handful of items your current call is returning, including the common prefixes that were creating manually at some point.

To list all available common prefixes, you'll need to enumerate all objects in the bucket and determine the list of common prefixes from there.  You can either do that with a full scan:

```python
def get_common_prefixes_by_list(s3, source_bucket, base_prefix=""):
    # List all objects in a bucket, and return only the prefixes
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    prefixes_seen = set()
    # Call into list_object_v2 to list all objects in the bucket
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=base_prefix)
    for page in pages:
        for obj in page.get('Contents', []):
            # Pull out the key for each object and split it into the parts 
            # based off the delimiter
            key = obj['Key']
            key = key.split('/')
            if len(key) > 1:
                # This object has at least one part to the prefix, so recreate 
                # the prefix portion of the object
                prefix = "/".join(key[:-1])
                if prefix not in prefixes_seen:
                    # And we've not previously seen this prefix, so return it
                    prefixes_seen.add(prefix)
                    yield prefix + "/"
```

Doing that will require listing all of the objects in the bucket.  For fairly small buckets, and/or buckets with deeply nested structures, that will work well enough.

If, however, you have a very large bucket that's composed of comparatively few number of common prefixes, doing that will take considerable time since the S3 API is limited to 1000 items in each call, and you might spend most of that work enumerating a large number of objects that share a prefix.  In that case, it's advantageous to utilize the convenience methods of the API to enumerate the structure:

```python
def get_common_prefixes_by_scan(s3, source_bucket, base_prefix=""):
    # List only the common prefixes in a bucket, enumerating
    # through all of the possibilities till there are no more
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

    # Keep a list of new prefixes we've seen to check in 
    # future passes
    prefixes_to_check = [base_prefix]
    while len(prefixes_to_check) > 0:
        current_prefix = prefixes_to_check.pop(0)
        # List all common prefixes under this prefix
        for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=current_prefix, Delimiter="/"):
            if len(page.get('CommonPrefixes', [])) == 0:
                # It's not officially documented, but in practice once ListObjectsV2 returns no more
                # common prefixes, it will not return anymore again, so bail out of the check here
                break
            for prefix in page.get('CommonPrefixes', []):
                prefix = prefix['Prefix']
                # Return the prefix, and add it to our list of prefixes to check
                yield prefix
                prefixes_to_check.append(prefix)
```

That will be much faster in those scenarios. Since it requires a separate call for each new prefix, it will probably be slower for a deeply nested layout of a few number of objects.