# Can we get the folder name only in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I have close to 1 Million objects in a bucket. I want to list the folders to a certain level alone without listing all the 1 million files - similar to how we can in file storage.

```
Eg: If bucket1 contains the following files then:
bucket1/1/xyz/**.pdf
bucket1/1/xyz/***.pdf
bucket1/1/xyz/*****.pdf
bucket1/1/yzx/*.pdf
bucket1/1/yzx/**.pdf
bucket1/1/yzx/***.pdf
bucket1/2/xyz/***.pdf
bucket1/3/xyz/***.pdf
.
.
1 million files

O/P should be only the folders.
bucket1/1/xyz/
bucket1/1/yzx/
bucket1/2/xyz/
bucket1/3/xyz/
```

Is there any workaround in s3 api to list the folders without going to the leaf files?

Comment: No such API exists.  In practice, with prefixes with million of objects, you can list the objects under a shared prefix and find the common prefixes with a few API calls [as shown in the second example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77135157/unable-to-retrieve-names-of-all-folders-in-s3-bucket-using-boto3/77135544#77135544).